Act and Potency Prescinded From Causality in Thomism
Did the Thomistic Commentators, including but not limited to Cajetan, prescind potency and act from causal relations? In other words, did they consider the notion of potency and act as separate from the notion of A causing B?

Please elaborate what you mean by "prescind potency and act from causal relations"?

@Germina: They abstracted or separated the notion of potency and act from the notion of A causing B, or so I think based on how I interpreted Cajetan and Reginald Garrigou Lagrange.

@Geremia, if you don’t mind me asking, have you read any Scholastic Manuals?

@Germia, is there a way I can chat with you without doing so in the comments?

Go here.

Actuality and potentiality are principles.
Thomistic Thesis:


Potency and Act so divide being that whatsoever exists either is a Pure Act, or is necessarily composed of Potency and Act, as to its primordial and intrinsic principles.

1. Potentia et actus ita dividunt ens, ut quidquid est, vel sit actus purus, vel ex potentia et actu tamquam primis atque intrinsecis principiis necessario coalescat.

De principiis naturæ:


[…] cause seems to add something to principle […] everything from which motion begins is called a principle […] a cause [is] that from whose existence another follows.

24. […] causa videtur addere supra principium […] omne id a quo incipit esse motus dicitur principium […] causa est ex cuius esse sequitur aliud.

